# Aframe preserve camera position on entering and exiting VR

Tags: three.js, aframe

I know in the recent update of Aframe 0.8.* the camera position is managed by WebVR Manager.

Just wanted to know can I somehow write a component for the camera to preserve its location upon entering and exiting VR mode.

It's pretty annoying that it relocates it to the center.

-Thanks

Comment: For the record I tried wrapping it in a-entity it stills pushes the camera 1.6 above and wasd moves the camera not the entity so this method is not good for building an interface on inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a-camera position="0 0 0"></a-camera>`

Comment: ?...

how is this gonna work?

It still overwrites the camera location upon entering in VR mode (through mobile)

Comment: This could use a little more explanation.